# How does Azure Data Explorer works. Internally, which database it uses

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there any documentation around the internal architecture and design of azure data explorer for internal developers?

Comment: "Internally, which database it uses" - it's a client for other database systems via plugins, like SQL Server and Data Lake. By "internally" are you asking about its own client state-management "database" and/or its configuration database? Or are you operating on the (mistaken) belief that ADE runs a copy of Azure's big-data services locally _in-process_?

Answer (score 5):

You can find an [overview blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-explorer-technology-101/) on the architecture of Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) and a bottom up architecture explanation including the technical description of the engine and the storage implementation in this [whitepaper](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/azure-data-explorer/).